How to Create a Fisheye Effect in an Image Carousel Using Circles in SwiftUI?
I'm working on an image carousel in SwiftUI where I want to create a fisheye effect  page control while sliding through the images. The idea is that the circle in the center should be larger, while the circles on either side gradually decrease in size, forming a fisheye effect.
Here is the reference image showing the desired effect.

Has anyone implemented something similar in SwiftUI, or can you point me in the right direction on how to approach this? Any code snippets or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Try using a scaleEffect on the individual dots. The effect used for the dots in your gif is not unlike the effect used for the carousel content in this answer, so you could see how it's being done there.

You didn't provide any code for your carousel, so I don't know exactly how you're going about it. But based on the gif example, this looks very much like a TabView with .tabViewStyle(.page).
The .page style can be configured to show the index dots, but they'd all be the same size:
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))

To achieve the "fisheye" effect, you will likely need to implement your own style, something like this.
If you need even more control over the appearance and animation of the dots, maybe look into .scrollTransition, which allows for the animation/customization of views as they approach, are in, and disappear from a specific visible region.
There are some videos from WWDC23 on this topic.
